# Change tooltip text of span element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m building a web application using jQuery. Then I m build this code

```
var tooltipText = "some text";
 <span  class="acd-maptooltip dotpatient" data-tooltip="' + tooltipText + '" id="beac" >;
```

this code are working.
Now, I want change dynamically the tooltip text on my span element.
I m using this code but it are not working:

```
var tooltipText = "another text";
 $('#beac').prop('data-tooltip', tooltipText);
```

Comment: This probably isn't working because the attribute is only read when the tooltip is created. Which tooltip library are you using?

Comment: I m using bootstrap